# Change Excel comment Shape Picture File format

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I want to change the file format of the comment shape picture (Fill) and as well as to a standard height and width. Tried the following code but it is keep on throwing Application defined error "Run time error 1004". Please guide me to correct this one.

```
Sub ReduceImageSize()

    Dim cmt As Comment
    Dim MyChart As Chart
    Dim MyPicture As String
    Dim pic As Object
    Dim PicWidth As Long
    Dim PicHeight As Long
    Dim num As Long
    num = 1
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each cmt In ActiveSheet.Comments
        With cmt
            .Visible = True
            .Shape.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
            .Visible = False
            PicHeight = .Shape.Height
            PicWidth = .Shape.Width

           Set MyChart = Charts.Add(0, 0, 100, 100).Chart
                With MyChart.Parent
                    .Width = PicWidth
                    .Height = PicHeight
                    .ChartArea.Select
                    .Paste
                    .ChartObjects(1).Chart.Export Filename:="C:\Temp\MyPic " & num & ".jpg", FilterName:="jpg"
                End With
                .Shape.Fill.UserPicture PictureFile:="C:\Temp\MyPic " & num - 1 & ".jpg"
                num = num + 1
                ActiveChart.Delete

            End With

    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing Format:=xlPicture to Format:=xlBitmap because jpg is a bitmap type image.  See the following from MS. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837557.aspx

And also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195475.aspx

Comment: Then why does your solution include  Format:=xlBitmap ?  You're welcome

Comment: The problem is with ChartObjects not with the format. I have to change Charts with chartObjects.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ReduceImageSize()
    Dim cmt As Comment
    Dim MyChart As ChartObject
    Dim MyPicture As String
    Dim pic As Object
    Dim PicWidth As Long
    Dim PicHeight As Long
    Dim num As Long
    Dim Mysheet As Worksheet
     num = 1
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each Mysheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
     For Each cmt In ActiveSheet.Comments
        With cmt
            .Visible = True
            .Shape.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
            .Visible = False
            PicHeight = .Shape.Height
            PicWidth = .Shape.Width

           Set MyChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, 100, 100)
                With MyChart
                    .Activate
                    .Width = PicWidth
                    .Height = PicHeight
                    .Chart.Paste
                    '.ChartArea.Select
                    '.Paste
                    .Chart.Export Filename:="C:\Temp\MyPic " & num & ".jpg", FilterName:="jpg"
                End With
                .Shape.Fill.UserPicture PictureFile:="C:\Temp\MyPic " & num & ".jpg"
                num = num + 1
                MyChart.Delete
            End With
      Next
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Next
End Sub
```